# Do not display out of stock products in reorder admin panel

Tags: magento2, sales-order, admin-panel

I don't want to show out of stock products in admin panel reorder or create new order option.[image]

Comment: this is by default feature, but you can see the message. Ex. your current screenshot.

Comment: Yes, But it let me create an order, which I don't want like this.